# perf_event_open - limit when monitoring multiple events

Tags: c, linux, profiling, perf

Does anyone know if there is a limit to the number of `PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE` events that we can monitor in a single group `PERF_FORMAT_GROUP`?

I am attempting to monitor multiple events and I am finding that I am able to monitor 5 events, but when I add a 6th hardware event the values of all registered events do not get updated.

```
struct read_format {
  uint64_t nr;          /* The number of events */
  struct {
    uint64_t value;     /* The value of the event */
    uint64_t id;        /* if PERF_FORMAT_ID */
  } values[nr];
};

int main() {
  struct perf_event_attr attr1;
  attr1.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
  attr1.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES;
  attr1.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID;
  int main_fd = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &attr1, 0, -1, -1, 0);
  uint64_t id1;
  ioctl(main_fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ID, &id1);
  ioctl(main_fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
  ioctl(main_fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

  struct perf_event_attr attr2;
  attr2.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
  attr2.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_REFERENCES;
  attr2.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID;
  int fd2 = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &attr2, 0, -1, main_fd, 0);
  uint64_t id2;
  ioctl(fd2, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ID, &id2);
  ioctl(fd2, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
  ioctl(fd2, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

  /*
  commenting out attr3 through attr 7. They are the same as attr2 except the following config:
  attr3.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_MISSES;
  attr4.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_BRANCH_MISSES;
  attr5.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_BUS_CYCLES;
  attr6.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_STALLED_CYCLES_FRONTEND;
  attr7.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_STALLED_CYCLES_BACKEND;
  */

  // read_values and log "START"

  // action

  // read_values and log "END"

  return 0;
}

read_values() {
  char buffer[4096];
  int read_bytes = read(main_fd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
  if (read_bytes == -1) { return 1; }

  struct read_format* rf = (struct read_format*) buffer;
  int values[rf->nr];
  for (int i=0; i<rf->nr; i++) {
    values[i] = rf->values[i].value;
  }
}
```

In the above code, all logged values at "START" and "END" have been updated when I only open perf events for attr1 - 5. However, when I attempt to open perf events for 6 events (or all 7 hardware events), all logged values at "START" and "END" remain the exact same.

I am able to get values of all 7 events if I read each one directly: `int fd2 = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &attr2, 0, -1, -1 /*!!instead of main_fd!!*/, 0);`, then performing a `read()` on each `fd`. But to reduce the number of `read` calls I'd prefer to read from the `main_fd` and grab the values from there. Is there a limit to the number of hardware events that can be captured in a single `PERF_FORMAT_GROUP`? I've noticed if the 6th and 7th events are software events that I don't see this issue.

Comment: How can you compile the `struct {
     …
  } values[nr];`?

Comment: It doesn't compile with that format. I copied that struct directly from perf_event_open docs to show the read_format. It is technically `struct {      …   } values[];` on my end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured I'd post an answer to my own question as I went down the rabbit hole and came across [this post](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/perf-list.1.html#event%20groups). Per the "Event Groups" section:

> The number of available performance counters depend on the CPU. A group cannot contain
> more events than available counters. For example Intel Core CPUs typically have four
> generic performance counters for the core, plus three fixed counters for instructions,
> cycles and ref-cycles. Some special events have restrictions on which counter they can
> schedule, and may not support multiple instances in a single group. When too many events
> are specified in the group some of them will not be measured.